# C: Read all *.txt files in a directory

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm trying to make a program that reads all `.txt` files in a directory. It obtains the name of each file using `file->d_name`, but now I need to open the files to work with them.

```c
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent* file;
    FILE *a;
    char ch;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Error\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    directory = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (directory == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    while ((file=readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", file->d_name);

            // And now????

        }

        closedir(directory);
    }
```

Comment: The c standard library has file access functions. You'll probably want fopen, fread and fclose. I'm assuming you're asking how to read files; your question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> ```
> while ((file=readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
> printf("%s\n",file->d_name);
>    //And now????
> }
> ```

1. Check whether the directory entry is a file or a directory. If it is not a regular file, move on to the next directory entry.

   ```
   if ( file->d_type != DT_REG )
   {
      continue;
   }
   ```
2. We have file. Create the name of the file by combining the directory name and the file name from the directory entry.

   ```
   char filename[1000]; // Make sure this is large enough.
   sprintf(filename, "%s/%s", argv[1], file->d_name);
   ```
3. Use standard library functions to open and read the contents of the file.

   ```
   FILE* fin = fopen(filename, "r");
   if ( fin != NULL )
   {
      // Read the contents of the file
   }
   ```
4. Close the file before processing the next directory entry.

   ```
   fclose(fin);
   ```

Comment: you might want to give filename length `strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(file->d_name) + 2`, instead of constant 1000 (assuming you're using c99 or c11). Allocating 1000 bytes on the stack might not be the best decision on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to see [file handling in c](http://www.studytonight.com/c/file-input-output.php)

```
while ((file=readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n",file->d_name);
    //To open file 
     a = fopen("file->d_name", "r+");   //a file pointer you declared


    }
```